# Remove the empty elements while using copy-of using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

*Ed: following from [Copy parallel element as child element of another element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270552/copy-parallel-element-as-child-element-of-another-element)*:

Input XML

```
<root>
   <order orderId="12345">
      <cartId>12346</cartId>
       <orderPayment paymentId="1234">
      <debitCardPayment>
         <chargeAmount currencyCode="USD">22.20</chargeAmount>
         <debitCard>
            <PIN>1234</PIN>  
            <PIN1></PIN1>               
         </debitCard>
      </debitCardPayment>
   </orderPayment>
   </order>
   <context>
   </context>       
</root>
```

### Need OUTPUT

```
<order>
  .....
</order>
 <orderPayment>
   .....
       <debitCard>
            <PIN>1234</PIN>  
         </debitCard>
</orderPayment>
<context>
</context>
```

I have XSLT as follows

```
<xsl:template match="Root">
        <updateOrderCheckoutRequest version="1"> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="//orderPayment"/>
        </updateOrderCheckoutRequest>
    </xsl:template>      

      <xsl:template match="orderPayment"/>

      <xsl:template match="order"> 
         <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy> 
      </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=".='' and count(@*)=0">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

Which is copying empty elements also.
Is there any possibility to remove empty elements while applying **copy-of**.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any possibility to remove empty elements while applying
>   copy-of.

No, it is not possible to use `xsl:copy-of` without copying everything as is. If you want to apply further changes to the nodes being copied, you must employ a different strategy, for example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::orderPayment)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="order">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../orderPayment"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now the `orderPayment` is being "copied" by virtue of the *identity transform* template - and you can add more specific templates to override, such as:

```
<xsl:template match="PIN1[not(string())]"/>
```

to remove empty `PIN1` elements.

Comment: @PSR This makes no sense: your new XSLT does **not** use `xsl:copy-of`.

Comment: Hi PSR, Add <xsl:template match="*[normalize-space(string(.)) = '']"/> at the end. This will remove all the empty elements, whatever the element is.

Comment: @PSR If your question is still about moving a branch of nodes to another place in the output tree and still being able to modify some of the nodes in the moved branch, then my answer remains the same. You should be able to make the necessary adjustments to your new situation yourself - provided you understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <updateOrderCheckoutRequest version="1"> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </updateOrderCheckoutRequest>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="order">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::orderPayment)]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="orderPayment"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(string())]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: i think then it only cheks PIN1

Comment: replaced `PIN1` with `*` to delete any empty elements.

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen It is working fine but ,there is another element named context ,which is coming last.Need to come before orderPayent.Check my updated question

Comment: Hi PSR, Add <xsl:template match="*[normalize-space(string(.)) = '']"/> at the end. This will remove all the empty elements, whatever the element is.

Comment: Is `context` empty? Please be specific and include everything in your question.

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen no context is not empty

Comment: If you run your given input XML against the stylesheet above, it would give your required output XML as stated, yet you said it should come before `orderPayment`. Please take time to fix your question and include there your explicit input and output requirements. Otherwise, we are only guessing.